# Javafx: adding more context information to an event

Tags: java, javafx

I have an alternative tree implementation because `Treeview` did not do what I needed it to do. It works great except for one thing: `event handling`.

The tree consists of logical nested objects and each object is represented using a multitude of hbox, vbox, labels, etc.

When you use the tree, you want to register your `event handlers on the root of the tree` and intercept all the events, this works however there is not enough context information.

You might get a mouse click event from a certain instanced Label but no way of checking which item in the tree it corresponds to. When building the tree the containers for each object *can* intercept the events and "enhance" them to provide new context information but I'm not sure how to do this.

The `copyFor()` is useless as it is overriden again when you fire the event. So how can I take generic events like `MouseEvent.ANY` and `KeyEvent.ANY` and `add a minimum amount of context?` `Am I forced to create my own events?`

**UPDATE**

For example if we have the tree:

```
A
   B
   C
```

In GUI elements it could look like this:

```
VBox(A)
   HBox(A)
       Icon(A)
       Label(A)
   VBox(B)
       HBox(B)
           Icon(B)
           Label(B)         
   VBox(C)
       ...
```

All event handler can be registered on the root VBox of A here. However suppose someone clicked on the Label(B) element, the root listener would only see that the original element is a Label. However as the listener, you want to know that it's linked to B.

Comment: Is this context related to the clicked label or mouse clicked event itself?

Comment: The clicked label is one of the many GUI elements used to display an item in the tree, I'll update with more info.

Comment: Why not call getParent() on the instance until you reach a TreeItem or whatever it is you're looking for?

Comment: @user1109519: good question on mouse handling!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you can utilize the `Node.setUserData()` method of the label/container/treeitem/tree for keeping its related context data. Then use it first by getting the source and target nodes of desired event. Otherwise, you may have to create your own events.

Comment: Interesting method, I didn't know it existed but it doesn't solve my problem entirely as each tree item contains a lot of GUI elements, I would have to set the user data on each of them because they could all be the source of the event.

Comment: Actually you did solve my problem. I now use setUserData() on the root VBox of the element (e.g. VBox(B)) and refire the event with that as target!